# Can you look up the producer/manufacturer that owns a certain "family" of EAN barcode?

Tags: data-request, barcodes

I have a barcode, `(9)8430709157279`, that I have tried to find in several online resources that collects EAN codes but so far without luck (the product is at least 20 years old so it is no surprise). However, is it possible to find out which company or similar this code was assigned to in the beginning?

In other words, does a company get something like `84307091xxxxx` and can use the "wildcards" however they like similar to IP-address ranges and MAC addresses ranges work? If so, can you lookup the prefix somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Using GS1's number search, you can look up who owns that [8430709157279 barcode](https://www.gs1us.org/tools/gs1-company-database-gepir).

```
Entity GLN
8430709000001

GS1 Company Prefix
8430709

Company
FERROLI ESPAÑA SLU
CL Alcalde Martin Cobos s/n. Pol. Ind. Villayuda.
Burgos 09007
```

Reading this data, the `8430709000001` is their identifier for the compnay and the prefix `8430709`leaves 5 digits of product and 1 check digit at the end.

How you make use of those 5 digits are up to the company using them. There is an algorithm to compute the check digit to make the barcode work with the barcode scanning industry.

You can use GS1's [calculator to verify](https://www.gs1.org/services/check-digit-calculator).

When you supply  `843070915727` the calculator reports the last digit should be `9`.

Barcode are fun!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Too bad I don't remember which product I was wondering about four years ago... Do you know if you can verify that this company "always" had this series of barcodes?